# ipod albums landscae view

Tags: iphone, view, mms

I would like to know if there's an API to implement a view which is similar to the iPod albums Landscape view. I tried using Scroll view but couldn't the get the required output.

Also, I would like to know if MMS can be implemented in an iPhone application. I did some searching, but no luck. Jailbreaking aside, is there any API which allows one to do that?

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try [OpenFlow](http://github.com/thefaj/OpenFlow)

Comment: Thanks much Morion! I have spent some time investigating but could not really find this way out. 

Any clue about my second query?

Comment: sorry, have no exp with jailbroken iPhones